# filter in subquery in nhibernate query

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have two tables in one-to-many relation:

```
product  -> orders
```

In the `Products` table (parent) I have the maximum number of products that I can sell,  and in the child table (orders) I have the number of products sold for each row.
I need to make a list of products that I have available in stock, filtered by

```
 orders.count() <= product.NumberOfProductsInStock
```

How can I accomplish this with a query in nhibernate?

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by "*filtered by*"? My answer may be wrong depending on what you mean by that...

Comment: What query implementation are you using in NHibernate, HQL, Criteria, Linq?

Comment: actually i use linq but i've seen that DefaultIfEmpty operator isn't supported at the moment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
CurrentSession.Linq<Product>()
    .Where(p => p.NumberOfProductsInStock > 0 && (p.Orders.Count() == 0 || p.Orders.Count() <= p.NumberOfProductsInStock))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That is an NHibernate query. What version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: i'm unable to find "Linq" method in session object :(

Comment: You want `ISession.Query`.

Comment: ok, but in this way if I have a record without any orders i'm unable to show it.. because it seems a inner join. it's rigth?

Comment: @ClaudioBarbera In the current query, yes. Is that something you *don't* want? Your actual requirements aren't 100% clear, what exactly is it you want to get out from the database? From your original question I gathered you wanted a list of products, in stock, which have a stock count <= the no. of orders...is that wrong?

Comment: in effect the question was not very clear ..
If the product has never been sold must fall in the stock so I should see it in the query results. I understand that you can not make a left join with linq to nhibernate, so I must use or HQL or queryOver. Is that right?

Comment: @ClaudioBarbera see my update, it should now include products that are in stock but haven't been sold.